# How to open command prompt when on Windows Server 2012 R2 Minshell when closed via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I've remote desktop onto a Min Shell server and closed the command prompt, how can I re-open this without rebooting the server. I've tried Win+R to open the run window but this isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does Ctrl+Shift+Esc work to bring up the Task Manager? If so, then use its File -> Run menu item.

Comment: I don't have a min shell server to test on right now or I would verify if this works myself.

Comment: Works perfectly.